# Dynamic switch cases

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I'm trying to make a simple switch case console menu for a few different users: `admin`, `moderator`, and `user`. `admin` would have `create, delete, modify, show` functions, `moderator` - `create, modify, show` functions, and `user` - `create, show` functions to choose from.

Admin switch case:

```
if(userType == "admin")
{
    string i = Console.ReadLine();
    switch(i):
    case "create": Console.WriteLine("Created");
                   break;
    case "modify": Console.WriteLine("Modified");
                   break;
    case "delete":Console.WriteLine("Deleted");
                  break;
    case "show":Console.WriteLine("Showed");
                break;
    default: Console.WriteLine("Default");
             break;
}
```

Moderator switch case:

```
if(userType == "moderator")
{
    string i = Console.ReadLine();
    switch(i):
    case "create": Console.WriteLine("Created");
                   break;
    case "modify": Console.WriteLine("Modified");
                   break;
    case "show": Console.WriteLine("Showed");
                 break;
    default: Console.WriteLine("Default");
             break;
}
```

User switch case:

```
if(userType == "user")
{
    string i = Console.ReadLine();
    switch(i):
    case "create": Console.WriteLine("Created");
                   break;
    case "show": Console.WriteLine("Showed");
                 break;
    default: Console.WriteLine("Default");
             break;
}
```

Is there any way to mold these switch cases into one dynamic switch? If I'm thinking or explaining something wrong, please correct me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The dynamic equivalent of a switch-case is a dictionary lookup.  For example:

```
Dictionary<string, Action> userActions = {
        { "create", () => Console.WriteLine("created") },
        { "show", () => Console.WriteLine("showed") } };
Dictionary<string, Action> adminActions = {
        { "create", () => Console.WriteLine("created") },
        { "show", () => Console.WriteLine("showed") },
        { "delete", () => Console.WriteLine("deleted") } };

Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Action>> roleCapabilities = {
        { "user", userActions },
        { "administrator", adminActions } };

roleCapabilities[userType][action]();
```

At runtime, you can easily add and remove allowed actions to each role (group).

In order to implement "default" logic, you'd use something like:

```
Action actionCall;
if (roleCapabilities[userType].TryGetValue(action, out actionCall)) {
   actionCall();
}
else {
   // this is the "default" block, the specified action isn't valid for that role
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a good candidate for the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

In the strategy pattern, functionality is represented by an object of an interface that can be passed around. Different implementations allow the behaviour to change dynamically.

For example:

```
interface ConsoleInteractor
{
    void performAction(string action);
}

class UserConsoleInteractor : ConsoleInteractor
{
    public void performAction(string action)
    {
        switch(i)
        {
            case "create": 
                Console.WriteLine("Created");
                break;
            case "show":
                Console.WriteLine("Showed");
                break;
            default: 
                Console.WriteLine("Default");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Switch (no pun intended) it around do check for role at each case.  And then if it is not allowed to do it, skip it.

```
string i = Console.ReadLine();
if (allowed(userType, i)){
  switch(i):
  case "create": Console.WriteLine("Created");
      handleCreate();
  break;
  case "show":Console.WriteLine("Showed");
      handleShow();
  break;
  case "delete":Console.WriteLine("Deleted");
      handleDelete();
  break;
  default: Console.WriteLine("Default");
    handleDefault(userType);
  break;
}
```

Comment: All that code duplication is asking for trouble.  Put the access check outside the switch, and pass in the variable `i` instead of a string literal.  Otherwise you'll someday accidentally code a test for read privilege when performing a mass erase.

Comment: you are correct, my point was to focus on a single point to do access control.

Comment: And in the process, introduced exactly the type of bug I was worried about.  Fixed now :)

Answer (score 2):

you are better off with a map of functions or Actions.

```
var actionsAdmin = new Dictionary<string, Action>{
  {"create", ()=>Console.WriteLine("create")}
  {"modify", ()=>Console.WriteLine("modify")}
}

var actionsUser = new Dictionary<string, Action>{
  {"show", ()=>Console.WriteLine("show")}
  {"foodle", ()=>Console.WriteLine("foodle")}
}
```

then choose the right map and execute the named function

```
var action = actionUser[verb];
action();
```

Comment: Great minds think alike ;)   +1 although I think another dictionary to look up the role ("choose the right map" in your words) is useful.