# trying to assign a checkedChanged event handler with variable Checkbox name

Tags: c#, checkbox

I am using C# and adding checkboxes programmatically to a windows form.  I am trying to assign a checkedChanged event handler to each checkbox created.  Is there a way to use a varable checkbox name in the following case statement?

```
CheckBox chkBox = new CheckBox();
chkBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(550, y2);
chkBox.Name = "CheckBox" + optno.ToString();
chkBox.Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
switch (optno)
{
   case 1:
      chkBox.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.**CheckBox1**_CheckedChanged);
      break;
   case 2:
      chkBox.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.CheckBox2_CheckedChanged);
      break;
   case 3:
      chkBox.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.CheckBox3_CheckedChanged);
      break;
```

I want to avoid a long list of cases.

Comment: You should probably combine your handlers.  Or make an array of delegates.

Comment: How different are the handler methods, really?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33107026/dynamic-switch-cases

Answer (score 0):

```
CheckBox chkBox = new CheckBox();
chkBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(550, y2);
chkBox.Name = "CheckBox" + optno.ToString();
chkBox.Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
chkBox.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.CheckBox_CheckedChanged);
```

Then the Handler would be:

```
private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;
  if (cb != null)
  {
    switch (cb.Name)
    {
      // a case statement for each combobox control...
      case "ComboboxOne":
        // call custom method for handling this checkbox's change
        DoComboboxOneStuff();
        break;
      case "ComboboxTwo":
        // call custom method for handling this checkbox's change
        DoComboboxTwoStuff();
        break;
    }
  }
}

private void DoComboboxOneStuff() 
{ // do your stuff here..}

private void DoComboboxTwoStuff()
{ // do your stuff here..}
```

Comment: `switch (cb.Name)` is bound to end in tears a few revisions down the line. I'd at least put an enum in their `Tag` properties or something.